# ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, undefined

Please help me with this error

HomeScreen.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, ScrollView, Image, FlatList} from 'react-native'
import React,{useState,useRef,useEffect} from 'react'

import { colors, parameters } from '../global/styles'
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE,} from 'react-native-maps';

import { Icon } from '@rneui/base'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import {filterData } from '../global/data'
import { mapStyle} from "../global/mapStyle"
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import incidentsAround from '../global/data';

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width

const HomeScreen = () => {

  const [latlng,setLatLng]= useState({})

  const checkPermission =  async()=>{
      const hasPermission = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (hasPermission.status === 'granted'){
        const permission = await askPermission();
        return permission
      }
      return true
  };

  const askPermission = async()=>{
    const permission = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
    return permission.status==='granted';
  };

  const getLocation = async()=>{
    try{
        const {granted} = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        if(!granted) return;
        const {
          coords:{latitude,longitude},
        } = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
        setLatLng({latitude:latitude,longitude:longitude})

    } catch(err){

    }
  }

  const _map=useRef(1);

  useEffect(()=>{
    checkPermission();
    getLocation()
   // console.log(latlng)
    ,[]
  })

  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.header}>
            <View style ={styles.icon1}>
                <Icon type = "material-community"
                        name ="menu"
                        color ={colors.white}
                        size ={40}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
        <ScrollView bounces ={false}>
            <View style ={styles.home}>
                <Text style = {styles.text1}> FDS360 Geo Alert</Text>
                <View style = {styles.view1}>
                    <View style ={styles.view8}>
                        <Text style={styles.text2}>La Patrie ou La Mort!</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text2}>Nous Vaincrons</Text>
                        <View style ={styles.button1}>
                            <Text style={styles.button1Text}> Nouveau trajet</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Image

                            style ={styles.image1}
                            source = {require('../../assets/burkina2.png')}

                        />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View>
                    <FlatList
                        numRows={4}
                        horizontal={true}
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                        data = {filterData}
                        keyExtractor ={(item)=>item.id}
                        renderItem={({item})=>(
                            <View style={styles.card}>
                                <View style={styles.view2}> 
                                    <Image style={styles.image2} source = {item.image} />

                                </View>
                                <View> 
                                    <Text style = {styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                        )}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style ={styles.view3}>
                  <Text style={styles.text3}> Destination?</Text>
                  <View style = {styles.view4}>
                    <Icon type = "material-community"
                          name ="clock-time-four"
                          color ={colors.grey1}
                          size ={26}
                    />
                    <Text style ={{marginLeft:5}}>Now</Text>
                    <Icon type = "material-community"
                        name ="chevron-down"
                        color ={colors.grey1}
                        size ={26}
                    />
                  </View>

                </View>
                <View style = {styles.view5}>

                  <View style = {styles.view6}>

                    <View style = {styles.view7}>
                      <Icon type = "material-community"
                          name ="map-marker"
                          color ={colors.black}
                          size ={22}
                      />

                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:colors.black}}> 32 Place de la nation</Text>
                      <Text style={{color:colors.grey3}}> Ouagadougou, Kadiogo</Text>
                    </View>

                  </View>

                  <View>

                      <Icon type = "material-community"
                              name ="chevron-right"
                              color ={colors.grey}
                              size ={26}
                      />

                  </View>

                </View>

                <View style={{...styles.view5, borderBottomWidth:0}}>

                  <View style = {styles.view6}>

                    <View style = {styles.view7}>
                      <Icon type = "material-community"
                          name ="map-marker"
                          color ={colors.black}
                          size ={22}
                      />

                    </View>
                    <View>
                      <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:colors.black}}> 32 Place de la nation</Text>
                      <Text style={{color:colors.grey3}}> Ouagadougou, Kadiogo</Text>
                    </View>

                  </View>

                  <View>

                      <Icon type = "material-community"
                              name ="chevron-right"
                              color ={colors.grey}
                              size ={26}
                      />

                  </View>

                </View>

                <Text style={styles.text4}> Perimetre</Text>

                <View style={{alignItems:"center"}}>

                  <MapView

                          ref={_map}
                          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                          style ={styles.map}
                          customMapStyle={mapStyle}
                          showsUserLocation={true}
                          showsMyLocationButton={true}
                          followsUserLocation={true}
                          rotateEnabled={true}
                          zoomEnabled={true}
                          toolbarEnabled={true}
                          region={{ ...incidentsAround[0], latitudeDelta:0.008, longitudeDelta:0.008}}
                          
                  >
               **   {incidentsAround.map((item,index)=>
                            <MapView.Marker coordinate = {item} key= {index.toString()}>
                                <Image 
                                    source = {require('../../assets/carMarker.png')}
                                    style ={styles.incidentsAround}
                                    resizeMode = "cover"
                                />
                            </MapView.Marker>
                            
                    )

                  }**

                  </MapView>        
                    </View>
            </ScrollView>
            <StatusBar style ="light" backgroundColor = "#2058c0" translucent ={true} />
        </View>
    )
}


export default HomeScreen
```

Got the " ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object " error after adding the lines below in my HomeScreen.js

```
{incidentsAround.map((item,index)=>
                            <MapView.Marker coordinate = {item} key= {index.toString()}>
                                <Image 
                                    source = {require('../../assets/carMarker.png')}
                                    style ={styles.incidentsAround}
                                    resizeMode = "cover"
                                />
                            </MapView.Marker>
                            
                    )

                  }*
```

I Also have data.js that contains the sample data

```
export const incidentsAround = [
    {latitude:12.30288166275722,longitude:-1.4946867345953474},
    {latitude:12.3049263,longitude:-1.4994025},
    {latitude:12.309804025004679,longitude:-1.4917235789684016},
    {latitude:12.310513362492223,longitude:-1.50309648930125},
    {latitude:12.308261887931687,longitude:-1.4965721956148201},
]
```

Full error log

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object

This error is located at:
in HomeScreen (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

Comment: I solved the issue by replacing "MapView.Marker" by "Marker" - Also imported it in HomeScreen import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps'